# How to check Dynamic Checkbox in React JS

Tags: reactjs, forms, checkbox

I have a dynamic form with the following implementation. The problem is that I want to "check" the checkbox IF the answer of that "questionID" exists in the answers array with the selected option (i.e A,B). so the condition of the check should be `answers[index].userChoice.option` is equal to Object.keys(x).
[image]

```
import fieldsL from "./fields.json"; 

function App() { 
  let [Fields , setFields] = useState([]);
  let [answers, setAnswers] = useState([]);
const updateAnswer = ((qid,option,optionValue) => {
      let ans = answers;
      let singleAns = {
        questionId : qid,
        userChoice: 
        { 
          option: option, 
          optionValue: optionValue, 
          isChecked: true
        }
      };
      if(answers.length > Fields) return console.warn("Invalid Question ID")
      if(answers.find((sp) => sp.questionId === qid)) {
        var index = answers.map(function(x1) {return x1.questionId}).indexOf(qid);
        answers[index].userChoice.option = option;
        answers[index].userChoice.optionValue = optionValue;
        console.log("Existing Answer Updated");
      }
      else ans.push(singleAns)
      ans.sort((a, b) => parseFloat(a.questionId) - parseFloat(b.questionId)); 
      setAnswers(ans)
      console.log(answers)
  })

useEffect(()=>{
  console.log("useEffect")
  setFields(fieldsL.data)
},[])
let Questions = fieldsL.data.question;
let displayFields = Questions.map((e,index)=>{
return <div key={index} >
<label className="label">{e.content}</label>

<div className="control">
{
e.radio?  e.option.map((x,index2) => {

  console.log(index)
  //console.log(x)
 return <div classID="field" key={index2}>
<div classID="control">
  <label classID="checkbox">
    <label> {Object.keys(x)[0]}     </label>

    <input type="checkbox" name="question" onChange={()=> updateAnswer(e.questionId,Object.keys(x)[0],Object.values(x)[0])}/>
    &nbsp; {Object.values(x)[0]}
    { 

    }
  </label>
</div>
</div> }
) : <span>Empty</span>
}
</div>
</div>;
})
```

Comment: I guess you want to add the `checked` prop to your input component. Probably something like `checked={answers[index].userChoice.option === Object.keys(x)}`.

Comment: @Chris How would I get the index right there.

Comment: Oh, I see. You need to first find the correct answer in the array?

Comment: Exactly, Since the Array is Dynamic, There is a chance that there is no value for it. in which case it will remain unchecked, same if the "option" doesn't match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In each iteration of your loop, you could do:

```
const value = Object.keys(x);
const answerIndex = answers.findIndex(a => a.userChoice.option === value);
```

and then in your return:

```
<input
  type="checkbox"
  name="question"
  checked={answerIndex >= 0}
  onChange={()=> updateAnswer(e.questionId,Object.keys(x)[0],Object.values(x)[0])}
/>
```

Obviously it would be better if your data was structured differently, as the above would give you an O(2n) complexity, since you'd be doing a loop inside a loop. However, for a smaller array, this shouldn't be an issue at all.

Comment: I tried that before & now, the index returns -1 for each iteration. https://prnt.sc/1tfxnvg

Comment: @FaqahatFareed perhaps I've misunderstood how your data is modeled. If the key of `x` is meant to match a `userChoice.option` then this should work.

Comment: The Correct key would be Object.keys(x)[0] however it also doesn't seem to work, Can you suggest a better implementation for this?

Comment: Can you update your question with console.log outputs of `answers` (the whole structure) and `Object.keys(x)`?